# Different colors for range selection in same Node

Tags: javascript, html, selection

I am trying to change background colors for selections on HTML nodes. I am able to do when do so until I have multiple selections in same element. Below picture is what I am currently able to do:
[image]

Is it possible to have different colors for these two selections, while they are in the same node?

**EDIT**

Below is what I want:

[image]

**EDIT 2 Adding code**

```
var index = getIndexOfText();
var multiple = checkMultiple();
var selection = window.getSelection();
if(index > -1) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    var clone;

    if(multiple) {

        range.setStart(ele, sI);
        range.setEnd(ele, sI + sE);
        clone = range.cloneRange();
    } else {
        range.setStart(ele, sI);
        range.setEnd(ele, sI + sE);
    }

    selection.addRange(range);
    while(index >= 0 && multiple) {
        index = ele.textContent.indexOf(ranges[i].text, index + ranges[i].text.length);
        if(index > -1) {
            selIndex = index;
            selEnd = ranges[i].text.length;
            clone.setStart(ele, selIndex);
            clone.setEnd(ele, selIndex + selEnd);
            console.log(multiple, index);
            selection.addRange(clone);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code you have tried so far, your question is formulated too generaly

Comment: Are you talking about using `::selection` here? That won’t be possible, you can not apply a property to only parts of an element, or specify a property to have different values on one and the same element.